# \Updating 11 to 12 with Update Manager - no progress?

Tags: upgrade

I've just run the Update Manager on Ubuntu 11 to upgrade to 12.

I was watching the 'terminal' output in the manager, with Thunderbird open in the background, when everything was hidden by my desktop backiground image. Or that is how it seems - every now and again I see the apps open, and then the bg covers them again.

Mouse is responding, no keyboard button seems to take effect (have not pressed ESC).

I've left it for an hour or so --- is this normal?  It's not a brand new machine, and although I don't know the specs, it is not terribly slow usually.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

This was 11 - 11.4, I think but I may be wrong - to 12 - 12.4 I thought, but I may be wrong.  In any case, I am using the Update Manager to perform the task: this is my first time, and it's not my machine, so I thought I'd try the simplest thing that would keep as much intact as possible.

Comment: You can not upgrade from ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 directly, please explain in your question what you did to -trying to- upgrade.

Comment: I rebooted and it sorted itself out, and the upgrade seems to have worked.